# How to enable remote Desktop sharing (like VNC server) for an OS running inside a docker container

Tags: docker, vnc-server

I was able to pull the `centos` image from docker hub  -

```
docker pull centos
```

Then I executed the run command to start the container with interactive mode -

```
docker run -i -t centos
```

After which I'm able to interact with `centos` running inside of the container through a terminal like -

```
[root@640fc383c7b4/]# other commands here..
```

Now I wanted to know if can interact with the `centos` inside of the container remotely, like using VNC viewer as I would do with other OS's running inside of virtual machines.

I tried installing `vncserver` with command `yum -y install tiger-vncserver` and running command `vncserver` after that which gives -

```
[root@640fc383c7b4 home]# vncserver

New '640fc383c7b4:2 ()' desktop is 640fc383c7b4:2

Starting applications specified in /root/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /root/.vnc/640fc383c7b4:2.log
```

Now I tried connecting to specified port `2` with IP address of container but it did not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the answer to your question is correct you should  consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to running container with any port you need to map it during run command and then access it via host IP or `localhost`.

For example:

If you running http server that listing on port 8080 inside a container to be able to access it on `8080` in your machine you need to map it like this  `8080:8080` the right side is container port, the left side is host port.

The command will look like this:

```
docker run -dit --name my-http-server-instance -p 8080:8080 my-http-server:latest
```

That goes the same for every other port.

In your case

- The port is probably not `2` so you need to find VNC server port (perhaps `5900`).
- You shouldn't use a container like this container is not a VM and maybe it's capable of doing it it's not meant to be use this way so consider using it from the command line connecting the container using ssh.

Comment: Why I shouldn't access the desktop remotely? any technical reason?

Comment: A Docker container isn't a full OS, it doesn't typically have multiple users, and you need to take care to set it up specially to not lose data on routine updates.  If your model of using it is "boot it and install software in it", that is a standard VM model, but a good way to lose work in Docker.